# FlieWriter con ciclo for

Tags: java, bucle-for, filewriter

Tengo este codigo y quiero que se modifiquen ciertas palabras y ocupo que se recorra el ciclo para que se modifique en cada vuelta pero solo me modifica una vez el archivo, me podrian decir en donde estoy mal o como hacer eso que estoy pensando?

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileWriter;

public class PruebaDeBuscarDentroDeUnArchivo {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
            new FileReader("C:\text.txt")
        );

        String line = "", content = "";
        while((line = reader.readLine())!= null) {
            content += line + "\r\n";
        }

        reader.close();

        String[] replacement={"cambialo ","usalo"};
        String[] needle ={ "public","static"};
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("test.txt");
    try{
    for(int i=0;i<=replacement.length;i++){

        String newContent = content.replaceAll(needle[i], replacement[i]);





        writer.write(newContent);
    }}catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){

    }
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException           e) {e.printStackTrace();
    } 
}
}
```

Comment: ¿Podrías aclarar a qué te refieres exactamente con "solo me modifica una vez el archivo"?

Comment: Claro, osea cuando se crea el archivo "test.txt" solo inserta el cambio de public--->cambialo y ya no cambia static--->usalo cuando por el ciclo deberia hacer ambas modificaciones solo que no se cual es el error en el codigo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El  `writer.write(newContent);`  ha de ir fuera del bucle. pero ademas tendriar que ir haciendo las sustituciones sobre el resultado que ya has obtenido.

Fuera del bucle  `String newContent = content;` 
 y dentro del bucle trabajara siempre con `newContent`

```
  import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.io.FileReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.FileWriter;

    public class PruebaDeBuscarDentroDeUnArchivo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                new FileReader("C:\text.txt")
            );

            String line = "", content = "";
            while((line = reader.readLine())!= null) {
                content += line + "\r\n";
            }

            reader.close();

            String[] replacement={"cambialo ","usalo"};
            String[] needle ={ "public","static"};
            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("test.txt");

            String newContent = content;
        try{

        for(int i=0;i<=replacement.length;i++){

            newContent  = newContent.replaceAll(needle[i], replacement[i]);


        }}catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){

        }
        writer.write(newContent);
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException           e) {e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }
    }
```

Comment: El problema con esa solucion, que ya la habia tratado de hacer xd es que el newContent al estar dentro del ciclo el wrter.write(newContent) ya no encuentra newContent

Comment: vale, tienes que declararlo fuera del try{}catch(){}, para que tenga visibilidad

Comment: muchas gracias, crei que nunca lo resolveria, esto de no practicar la programacion por 2 a;os si que me afecto xd

Answer (score 0):

Tenías un par de cosas a corregir en tu código, que quedaría así:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                new FileReader("C:\\Users\\ivcl\\Desktop\\text.txt")
        );
        String[] replacement = {"cambialo ", "usalo"};
        String[] needle = {"public", "static"};
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\ivcl\\Desktop\\test.txt");

        String line = "", content = "";
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            content += line + "\r\n";
        }

        reader.close();

        String newContent = content;
        for (int i = 0; i < replacement.length; i++) {
            newContent = newContent.replaceAll(needle[i], replacement[i]);
            writer.write(newContent);
        }

        writer.flush();
        writer.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Básicamente, la variable que usas para escribir (newContent) la estabas declarando en cada vuelta del bucle, motivo por el que no te estaba "acumulando" las sustituciones.

El segundo problema era la condición que usabas en ese bucle (i <= replacement.length). Los arrays en java van de la posición 0 a la tamaño-1. Al tener tu la condición con ese <=, estabas intentando acceder a una posición que ya no existe, motivo por el que se te producían esos ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsExceptions y que te forzaban a usar un try/catch. Tu programa funcionaba, obviamente, pero lanzar y capturar excepciones siempre es costoso y no tienes necesidad de hacerlo si no es, como su nombre indica, algo realmente excepcional.

Por otro lado, de la manera que lo estás haciendo estás almacenando en una única variable el contenido de todo el fichero que lees. Si éste fuese muy grande, podrías tener problemas de memoria, por lo que, tal vez, sea mejor hacer la sustitución en cada línea cuando la has leído y directamente escribirla en el fichero de salida en vez de hacerlo de una sola vez al final.

Espero haberte servido de ayuda.

Comment: Muchas gracias por mostrarme en donde fue que me equivoque, si si note ese ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsExceptions cuando ponia el <= pero lo seguia intentado asi a sabiendas de que estaba mal, de nuevo muchas gracias me sirve mucho ya que habia dejado de programar y de plano no recordaba nada